# simplify the term: $\int\limits_{U} u_{t} + u u_x - u_{x x} + u_{x x x x}=0$ By using Green's identity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This situation came under a problem on PDE.
Let $u(x,t)$ is a sufficiently smooth function defined on $U=(0,L)\times(0,T)$
I have to simplify the term:
$$\int\limits_{U} u_{t} + u u_x - u_{x x} + u_{x x x x}=0$$
By using Green's identity. 
Also the initial values given as:
$u(x,0)= 0$ where $x\in(0,L)$
$u(0,t) = u(L,t) =  u_{xx}(0,t) = u_{xx}(L,t)=0$ where $t\in(0,T)$
This is think I can properly substitute those if the main term is simplified a little further...

I tried:
1. Multiplying everything by $u_t$
2. writing the $u_{xx}$ term as $\Delta -u_{tt}$
3. Also even simplifying by writting: $\int\limits_{U}^{}\cdot=\int\limits_{0}^{T}\int\limits_{0}^{L}\cdot dxdt$ (Which I'm not sure whether this holds true)

But none of those gave me a suitable simplification. May be there are other techniques available or I might have missed an important step in the middle. I specially think that the first method should make the term simplified but it didn't work for me

Can someone please help.

Comment: Do you mean multiplying everything by $u$?

Comment: @xpaul Nope.. I tried multiplying with $u_t$ (the partial with respect to $t$). Do you think that multiplying by $u$ would work?

Comment: I think so. Try this.